# In scala 2.13. How to log information/warning/error reliably in macro?

Tags: scala, implicit, scala-macros, scala-macro-paradise, scala-2.13

I'm writing a macro that can log a short message during the compilation, using pattern matching and constant type feature of scala 2.13:

```
class EmitMsg[T, SS <: EmitMsg.EmitLevel] {}

object EmitMsg {

  trait EmitLevel

  trait Info extends EmitLevel
  trait Warning extends EmitLevel
  trait Error extends EmitLevel
  trait Abort extends EmitLevel

  def create[A, SS <: EmitMsg.EmitLevel]: EmitMsg[A, SS] = new EmitMsg[A, SS]

  implicit def emit[A, SS <: EmitMsg.EmitLevel]: EmitMsg[A, SS] = macro Macros.emit[A, SS]

  final class Macros(val c: whitebox.Context) {
    val u = c.universe
    import u._

    def outer: EmitMsg.type = EmitMsg.this

    def emit[A: c.WeakTypeTag, LL: c.WeakTypeTag]: c.Tree = {

      val aa: Type = weakTypeOf[A]
      val v = aa match {
        case v: u.ConstantType => v.value.value
        case _ =>
          throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
            s"type $aa is not a constant"
          )
      }
      val ss = "" + v
      val ll: Type = weakTypeOf[LL]

      // if inherited from multiple traits, take the most serious one
      if (ll <:< weakTypeOf[Abort]) {
        c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, ss)
      } else if (ll <:< typeOf[Error]) {
        c.error(c.enclosingPosition, ss)
      } else if (ll <:< typeOf[Warning]) {
        c.warning(c.enclosingPosition, ss)
      } else if (ll <:< typeOf[Info]) {
        c.info(c.enclosingPosition, ss, force = true)
      } else {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
          s"type $ll is not an EmitLevel"
        )
      }

      q"$liftOuter.create[$aa, $ll]"
    }
  }
}
```

When being tested, I found that the macro works most of the time when being invoked directly:

```
EmitMsg.emit["ABC", EmitMsg.Error]
EmitMsg.emit["ABC", EmitMsg.Warning]
...
```

(this generates proper compilation messages):

```
[Error] /home/peng/git/shapesafe/macro/src/test/scala/org/shapesafe/m/EmitMsgSpec.scala:19: ABC
[Warn] /home/peng/git/shapesafe/macro/src/test/scala/org/shapesafe/m/EmitMsgSpec.scala:20: ABC
one warning found
```

... but rarely works if being part of the implicit macro pattern (https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/implicits.html):

```
  it("can emit error") 

    type TT = EmitMsg["ABC", EmitMsg.Error]
    implicitly[TT] //(EmitMsg.emit)
  }
/*
 Generates the following Message:

[Error] /home/peng/git/shapesafe/macro/src/test/scala/org/shapesafe/m/EmitMsgSpec.scala:15: could not find implicit value for parameter e: TT
*/

  it("can emit warning") {

    type TT = EmitMsg["ABC", EmitMsg.Warning]
    implicitly[TT] //(EmitMsg.emit)
  }
/*
Doesn't do a thing
*/

  it("can emit info") {

    type TT = EmitMsg["ABC", EmitMsg.Info]
    implicitly[TT] //(EmitMsg.emit)
  }
/*
Doesn't do a thing
*/
```

So my questions are:

- Is calling c.info/warning/error the correct way of logging in compile-time?
- If so, why they never works as part the implicit macro pattern?

Thanks a lot for your suggestions!

**UPDATE 1** Just found a solution for one case (Error) at https://github.com/fthomas/singleton-ops/blob/204195838ada34de7e453401fb06810ace2c99b0/src/main/scala/singleton/ops/impl/GeneralMacros.scala#L102

```scala
    val tree0 =
      c.typecheck(
        q"""
          new _root_.scala.annotation.implicitNotFound("dummy")
        """,
        silent = false
      )

    class SubstMessage extends Transformer {
      val global = c.universe.asInstanceOf[scala.tools.nsc.Global]

      override def transform(tree: Tree): Tree = {
        super.transform {
          tree match {
            case Literal(Constant("dummy")) => Literal(Constant(msg))
            case t => t
          }
        }
      }
    }

    val tree = new SubstMessage().transform(tree0)

    annotatedSym.setAnnotations(Annotation(tree))
    ()
```

This is a convoluted hack, it works by adding an @implicitNotFound annotation on the definition of the implicit function. I'm not aware of any similar solution for Warning and Info cases so far. Nevertheless, a simpler solution is always preferred

Answer (score 0):

Just make `c` a `blackbox.Context` rather than `whitebox.Context` if you don't want to postpone compile errors during implicit resolution.